# Cannot ReDeclare get_class() Fatal Error

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to apply the class `effect` into `input type="submit"` whenever its attributed form action contains the string `special`.

I'm getting a

> **Fatal error**: Cannot redeclare get_class() on line 16

Code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$case1 = "special"; 
$a = "aaa"; 
$item = "something"; 

function get_class( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => 'effect',
        'none'    => ''
    );

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
} // Line 16
?>

<HTML>
<body>
    <form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case1 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="<?php get_class( $case1 ); ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) already exists. You need to change the function's name (e.g: `get_css_class`) or use [namespace](http://php.net/manual/it/language.namespaces.php).

```
namespace Acme;

function get_class($slug) { // that's okay
```

Comment: ok, I changed to `get_classb`, it runs, but code itself doesn't work, the class `effect` is not being added

Comment: you need to use `<?php echo get_class( $case1 ); ?>`

Comment: oh missed that, I thought I was using the short non-echo form, thanks!